# Replacing values in a select statement

Tags: mysql

So, sorry as I feel this is an already asked question, but I was unable to correctly word it to find results matching my needs.

I have these 4 tables:

Participants:

```
id     |     name
----------------------
1      |     Name1
2      |     Name2
3      |     Name3
4      |     Name4
5      |     Name5
6      |     Name6
```

Events:

```
id      |     participant1   |  participant2
----------------------------------------------
7       |     2              |    1
8       |     2              |    1
9       |     3              |    1
10      |     4              |    3
11      |     5              |    4
12      |     6              |    5
```

EventGroups:

```
id     |     groupId      |  eventId
----------------------------------------------
1      |     1            |    7
2      |     1            |    8
3      |     1            |    9
4      |     2            |    10
5      |     2            |    11
6      |     2            |    12
```

Groups:

```
id     |     name
----------------------
1      |     GroupName1
2      |     GroupName2
```

So, until now I have this:

```
Select * from EventGroups eg 
  join Groups g on eg.groupId = g.id
  join Events e on e.id = eg.eventId;
```

And this is the result:

```
id |  groupId  |  eventId |   name        |  participant1   |  participant2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |     1     |    7     |   GroupName1  |       2         |       1
2  |     1     |    8     |   GroupName1  |       2         |       1
3  |     1     |    9     |   GroupName1  |       3         |       1
4  |     2     |    10    |   GroupName2  |       4         |       3
5  |     2     |    11    |   GroupName2  |       5         |       4
6  |     2     |    12    |   GroupName2  |       6         |       5
```

And the desired output would be:

```
id |  groupId  |  eventId |   name        |  participant1   |  participant2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |     1     |    7     |   GroupName1  |   Name2         |     Name1
2  |     1     |    8     |   GroupName1  |   Name2         |     Name1
3  |     1     |    9     |   GroupName1  |   Name3         |     Name1
4  |     2     |    10    |   GroupName2  |   Name4         |     Name3
5  |     2     |    11    |   GroupName2  |   Name5         |     Name4
6  |     2     |    12    |   GroupName2  |   Name6         |     Name5
```

I mean, replacing the participant Id in each column by it's corresponding name in the matching table.

Language is Mysql.

Would be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much @Phiter as it's working perfectly! ^^

And sorry community on duplicating the question, I didn't know how to word it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the participant table twice, one for each participant and then use participant1 and participant2 as aliases for the matching participant's names.

```
Select eg.id, eg.groupId, eg.EventId, g.name, p1.name as participant1, p2.name as participant2  from EventGroups eg 
  join Groups g on eg.groupId = g.id
  join Events e on e.id = eg.eventId
  join Participants p1 on p1.id = e.participant1
  join Participants p2 on p2.id = e.participant2;
```